# apache mod_rewrite subdomain to dir

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, directory, subdomain

I have 4 servers, and I want to merge them with a domain. For example, what I am doing now:

- games.example.org
- [www.example.org](http://www.example.org)
- etc ..

I want to

If any one access [www.example.org/games/](http://www.example.org/games/)

I want to show in the browser [www.example.org/games/](http://www.example.org/games/) virtually but physically it files will be hosted in the games.example.org server?

Comment: Is games.example.org a separate server, or just another virtual server, hosted on the same machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure mod_rewrite rules will not be enough, since they require mod_proxy as well to make the subrequests work correctly. Especially if you want all the absolute links to be auto rewritten as the page is served back. If you have full access to Apache, this code can be used in the virtualhost section of your www.example.org domain:

```
<Location  /games>
        ProxyPassReverse http://games.example.org
        ProxyPassReverse http://games.example.org:80

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule games(.*)$ http://games.example.org/$1 [QSA,P,L]
</Location>
```

The last RewriteRule is really what you need, but the "P" flag will likely not work unless you can load mod_proxy as well. Make sure to load mod_proxy with the most restrictive settings and allow proxy requests though the ProxyPass directives.

Also ProxyPassReverse will NOT work in .htaccess. It has to be in the Apache vhost config itself.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks mate, its wonderful, but my question now, if i want to access http://games.example.org/signup/ with this rewrite rule i can access it throw http://www.examples.org/games/signup/ ? kindest regards

Comment: Exactly! It should get anything games(.*) and forward it to the correct URL. Actually one correction above (which I'll edit), the rewrite rule is supposed to reference the subdomain and not the original domain.

Comment: what i am having now

<Location  /games>
    ProxyPassReverse http://games.example.com
    ProxyPassReverse http://games.example.com:80
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule games(.*)$ http://games.example.com/$1 [QSA,P,L]
    </Location>

it's working but its giving me this url www.example.com/web/login.php which will raise 404 page not found how can i append word games in any URL by being like this www.example.com/games/web/login.php ?